# Can I use my Cognito credentials to authenticate against AWS services using the AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-net

I want to download files from S3 buckets to a Windows machine using a Cognito user.

I've created a user pool, created a new demo user and also created an app client with the authorization code flow enabled. Afterwards, I created a new role which just gives full access to the AWS S3 service, assigned this role to a group and assigned my demo user to this group.

In my .NET 8 app, I open the web browser, redirects the user to the Cognito login page & redirect back to the web server of the app. With the gathered authorization code I then get an OAuth 2.0 token.

I now need to assume a role using the secure token service providing my OAuth 2.0 credentials & then receive AWS credentials which then can be used to call S3 using the SDK.

I'm using the `AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient`, But I get the error:

> Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service

How does the EC2 service come into play?

What's the issue with the `AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient`?

And, how can I access S3 using my Cognito credentials??

This is my code:

```cs
// Get AWS credentials using the identity pool
AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient securityTokenServiceClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.EUNorth1);
AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse roleResponse = await securityTokenServiceClient.AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityAsync(new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest()
{
    WebIdentityToken = tokenResponse?.IdToken,
    RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/cognito-demo-bucket",
    RoleSessionName = "demo"
});

_logger.LogTrace("Access key: {awsCredentials}\nSecret access key: {secretAccessKey}", roleResponse.Credentials.AccessKeyId, roleResponse.Credentials.SecretAccessKey);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the EC2 service come into play?

The reason you get `Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service` is due to how the AWS SDK for .NET searches for credentials.

The [default credentials provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-assign.html) for the .NET SDK searches for credentials in a specific order, one by one. If all else fails, currently, the final place the credentials provider looks at is:

> 8. Amazon EC2 instance metadata.

Since the .NET SDK can't find any credentials anywhere for your application in the other 7 locations, its final attempt is at loading them from the EC2 instance metadata endpoint under the metadata item [`iam/security-credentials/{role-name}`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

Since you're not running on an EC2 instance, that also fails and the SDK errors out with the above error message - basically saying: *I can't find any credentials anywhere*.

---

> What's the issue with the `AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient`?

The `AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient` in this case does not need *any AWS credentials*. It is being used to call the [`AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) operation, which exchanges the Cognito ID token for temporary AWS credentials.

As per docs:

> Calling `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` does **not require the use of AWS security credentials**.

Therefore, you need to tell the AWS SDK to not sign the request.

For the .NET SDK, you can do this by using the [`AnonymousAWSCredentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/TAnonymousAWSCredentials.html) class:

```cs
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.SecurityToken;

var anonymousCredentials = new AnonymousAWSCredentials();
var stsClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(anonymousCredentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
```

---

> And, how can I access S3 using my Cognito credentials?

Use [`SessionAWSCredentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/TSessionAWSCredentials.html); for Amazon S3, here's a full working, minimal example that lists the objects in a bucket:

```cs
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.SecurityToken;
using Amazon.SecurityToken.Model;

var anonymousCredentials = new AnonymousAWSCredentials();
var stsClient = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(anonymousCredentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

var assumeRoleResponse = await stsClient.AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityAsync(new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest
{
    RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/cognito-demo-bucket",
    RoleSessionName = "xxx",
    WebIdentityToken = "yyy"
});

var assumedCredentials = new SessionAWSCredentials(
    assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
    assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SessionToken
);

var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(assumedCredentials);

var bucketName = "xyz";
var listObjectsResponse = await s3Client.ListObjectsAsync(bucketName);
```

Comment: Thanks! The stuff now makes a lot more sense for me. Unfortunately when assuming the role it seems that I don't have enough permissions to do so: "Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity". Since the call is made anonymous, where do I have to add this permission?

Comment: As I'm digging deeper in the topic I saw that the default IAM role which has been created by the Cognito user pool is matching the audience as trusted entity of my ID token as follows: `"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<identity-pool-id>"`. But in the ID token itself the audience has the format `"aud": "<client-id>"`. Maybe this can give a clue. But for today I'm raising my white flag against the AWS SDK.

Comment: @LouBen3010 No worries, for the new error please look online or feel free to create a new question as it would be offtopic from this one :)